# Sending Bitmap data over winsock? Winapi

Tags: tcp, ip, winsock, send, recv

I am tring to send a screenshot of a desktop over winsock.

As such, there are four tasks:

```
Save bitmap to buffer
Write data across wire using a socket
Read data from wire using a socket
Load a bitmap from a buffer
```

I have saved the bitmap to a char array using GetDIBits.
Writing the data to the server, I have done but I have questions.
For writing data over from server to the client, do I need to use only 1 recv() call (I am using TCP), or do i need to split it up into multiple parts? Ive read that TCP is stream concept and that I wouldnt have to worry about packets because that is abstracted for me?

How would I go about loading the information from GetDIBits into a bitmap and displaying it on the main window?

I am guessing I have to use SetDIBits, but into which device contexts do i use?

The Server screenshot capturer is here:

```
 HDC handle_ScreenDC = GetDC(NULL);
HDC handle_MemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(handle_ScreenDC);
BITMAP bitmap;


int x = GetDeviceCaps(handle_ScreenDC, HORZRES);
int y = GetDeviceCaps(handle_ScreenDC, VERTRES);

HBITMAP handle_Bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(handle_ScreenDC, x, y);
SelectObject(handle_MemoryDC, handle_Bitmap);

BitBlt(handle_MemoryDC, 0, 0, x, y, handle_ScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

GetObject(handle_Bitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap);

BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfHeader;
BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;

bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bi.biWidth = bitmap.bmWidth;
bi.biHeight = bitmap.bmHeight;
bi.biPlanes = 1;
bi.biBitCount = 16;
bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bi.biSizeImage = 0;
bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bi.biClrUsed = 0;
bi.biClrImportant = 0;
//std::cout<< bitmap.bmWidth;
DWORD dwBmpSize =((bitmap.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 5) / 32) * 4 * bitmap.bmHeight;
//int i = bitmap.bmWidth;
//DWORD dwBmpSize = 99;

HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwBmpSize);

char* bufptr = (char *)GlobalLock(hDIB);

GetDIBits(handle_ScreenDC, handle_Bitmap, 0, (UINT)bitmap.bmHeight, bufptr, (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);


send(clientsock, bufptr , GlobalSize((char *)GlobalLock(hDIB)), 0);
/*Do i need to packetize/split it up? Or 1 send() is good for the matching Recv on the client?*/
/*I am assuming i must send bi structure over winsock also correct?*/
```

And The receiveing client code:

```
        case WM_PAINT:{

        //Im a Gdi beginner so I dont have a clue what im doing here as far as blitting the recved bits, this is just some stuff i tried myself before asking for help

        PAINTSTRUCT paintstruct;

        HDC handle_WindowDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &paintstruct);

        handle_MemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(handle_WindowDC);


        handle_Bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(handle_WindowDC, 640, 360);


         std::cout << SetDIBits(handle_MemoryDC, handle_Bitmap, 0, bi.biHeight, buffer, (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

        SelectObject(handle_MemoryDC, handle_Bitmap);

        StretchBlt(handle_WindowDC, 50, 50, 640, 360, handle_MemoryDC, 0, 0, x, y, SRCCOPY);


        EndPaint(hwnd, &paintstruct);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sockets do have limited buffer sizes at both ends, typically around 4000 bytes.  So if you dump a large block of data (like a full screendump) in one call to a non-blocking send, you will likely get errors, and you will need to manage your own buffers, calling multiple sends.  However, if you are using non-blocking socket, you should be OK, as send() will simply block until all the data is sent.

On the receiving side, it is a similar case - a blocking receive can just keep waiting until it has the full data size that you asked for, but a non-blocking receive will return with whatever data is available at that time, which will result in the data filtering through bit by bit, and you will need to reassemble the data from multiple recv() calls.

I have heard of issues with sending really large blocks of data in one hit, so if you are sending 5 megabytes of data in one hit, be aware there might be other issues coming into play as well.